# ASP.net Create a directory - Access denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, directory, export-to-csv

I am making an ASP.NET MVC application and I would like users to be able to save files to a folder.

I have this code:

```
if (!Directory.Exists("~/CSVfiles/" + userDetails.Username))
  Directory.CreateDirectory("~/CSVfiles/" + userDetails.Username);
```

So if the user does not have a folder in the directory specified then make one. 
Firstly is this a correct way to find a folder -> "~/CSVfiles/"

When it has created this folder I then want to be able to save a file to that folder 
I have this code:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("~/CSVfiles/" + userDetails.Username + "/doc.csv", CSV);
```

I have List CSV <- this is a list of strings comma separated.

I am currently getting this error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
{"Access to the path '~/CSVfiles/User1' is denied."}
```

Answer (score 1):

Directory is part of the common IO namespace and does not understand shorthand signs like '~' of ASP.NET. You have to convert it to some actual path...
You may use [Page.ResolveUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [VirtualPathUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...

Comment: var content = Server.MapPath("~/CSVfiles/");

Answer (score 0):

Your asp.net users need to have permission on that folder. Check if asp.net app pool users have write access to your folder.